# Determine the exact value of $\prod_{n=3}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}n)}$

Tags: geometry, limits

> Determine the exact value of $\prod_{n=3}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}n)}$

I found an estimate for this limit by running a computer program, but I would like to determine how to derive it computationally. Also, I was wondering if this had a closed form.

Comment: Relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonCircumscribing.html, http://oeis.org/A051762.

Comment: Mathematica did not give me a closed form.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Perhaps consider writing up a few key points from that article? That's as close to a complete answer as it's reasonable for OP to expect.